# what should i configure to stop nutch re-index or fetch again. It should index only once for a url

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Can any one point me right documentation or hack to stop nutch re-index or fetch same content.
I want to crawl only once for a given url

Comment: Hi Tousif,
Every poor details provided in your question for anybody to answer your question... 
1) What commands you are executing to index the document? 
2) Why do you say that nutch will re-index or fetch the same content  again?

Comment: @JayeshBhoyar Its pretty common that every crawler will refetch and index content. now what i asked is how can i avoid re fetch. Don't you think google visits website for fresh content?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the processes that nutch performs:

1. Fetches the seed URL
2. Generates URL from that Seed URL
3. Creates a linkDB
4. Fetches the content of only those link which are new to Nutch or checksum is changed (i.e. modified URL)
5. It will fetch the content and parse the content for only those links which are new or modified.
6. For other URLs, it just generates the URL and keeps it in the link DB.

Example:

1. In first crawl Nutch fetched, generates and crawled content from 10 URLs.
2. Now say 3 links are added in my website
3. In second fetch /re-indexing, Nutch will visit all the 13 URLs, and generate the URL and keep it in the linkdb, but only fetch the content for newly-added 3 URLs and fetch the content and parse it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.